# Hyperledger Composer permission.ACL

Tags: acl, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I want the `Seller` see just his account: `Seller` has `READ` access on his `Account`. But my rule below don't work. How can I do this?

```
//Sellers to have read access to Account asset
rule SellerReadAccessAccountsRecord {
description: "Allow seller read access to his Account asset"
participant(p): "org.acme.biznet.Seller"
operation: READ
resource(r): "org.acme.biznet.Account"
condition: (r.owner.getIdentifier() === p.getIdentifier())
action: ALLOW
}
```

Comment: It will be `condition: (r.owner.getIdentifier() == p.getIdentifier())`.

Comment: It would be better If you add model file.

Comment: My model for Seller and Account: </br>   participant Seller identified by sellerId extends Member {
  o String sellerId
  o String firstName
  o String lastName
  --> Wallet wallet
  --> Account account
}

Comment: Did you check after updating condition which mentioned in the first comment?

Comment: yes, but it doesn't work too.

Comment: asset Account identified by accountId {
  o String accountId
  o String currency default="EUR"
  o String ownerId
  o Double balance default=0.0
}

Comment: How did you get `owner.getIdentifier()` in `Account` resource?

Answer (score 1):

If you `Account` model look like:

```
asset Account identified by accountId { 
o String accountId 
o String currency default="EUR" 
--> Seller owner
o Double balance default=0.0 
}
```

Then your current permission will work. Otherwise condition in your permission need to change like following:

```
condition: (r.ownerId == p.getIdentifier())
```

Comment: So that modified condition from your comment works! Now i want the Seller can create Asset e.g AirQualityData, but if the owner of the Asset has changed, the Seller has just READ access. What would be the conditions for this? I assume for CREATE access it's similar to other: condition: (r.ownerId == p.getIdentifier()). But how is it with READ access?

Comment: with other words, as long as the Seller is the owner, he has CREATE and READ access on Asset. If ownership has changed, the Seller has just READ access.

Comment: According to you permission `Seller` can read the asset only if he is the owner of that asset. If ownership has changed of that asset then he will not be able to read that asset.

Comment: My idea is, the Seller creates an Asset and transfers it to other participant. Later the Seller should be able to see, what was the Asset and who is the new owner of Asset.

Comment: Maybe it's just nonsense, what I wrote. The Seller should see what was the transactionId  and so he can get the informations.

Comment: If you want to implement your idea you should keep track of Asset transfer which is called `Transaction` and you should add permission for that transaction.

Answer (score 0):

So that's my solution:

//Seller to have read/write/update access to own air pollution data assets

```
rule SellerAccessAirPollutionDataRecord {
    description: "Allow sellers read/write/update access to own air pollution data assets"
    participant(p): "org.acme.biznet.Seller"
    operation: CREATE, UPDATE, READ
    resource(r): "org.acme.biznet.AirPollutionData"
    condition: (r.owner.getIdentifier() == p.getIdentifier())
    action: ALLOW
}
```

//Seller to have read access to sold air pollution data assets

```
rule SellerReadAccessAirPollutionDataRecord {
    description: "Allow sellers read access to sold air pollution data assets"
    participant(p): "org.acme.biznet.Seller"
    operation: READ
    resource(r): "org.acme.biznet.AirPollutionData"
    condition: (r.owner.getIdentifier() != p.getIdentifier())
    action: ALLOW
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sellers to have read access to Account asset

```
rule SellerReadAccessAccountsRecord {
description: "Allow seller read access to his Account asset"
participant(p): "org.acme.biznet.Seller"
operation: READ
resource(r): "org.acme.biznet.Seller"
condition: (r.getIdentifier() == p.getIdentifier())
action: ALLOW
}
```

For more information look at [here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/acl-trading)